# ASP.Net MVC custom datatype passing additional values

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I have created the custom "DataType" annotation to use on the model object to tell this is the date field on the view. (`[DataType("Date")]`) If I use `@Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateCreated)`, it will act as a date field and pup up the JavaScript date picker. This is the template I am using under EditorTemplates

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<DateTime> 
<div class="input-append date" data-date="12-02-2012">
    <input type="text" class="span2">
</div>
```

View -

```
<div class="control-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DateCreated, new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div class="controls" id="date-container">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DateCreated, new { @class="input-append date"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DateCreated, null, new { @class = "help-inline" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Model -

```
[Display(Name = "Date Created")]
[DataType("Date")]        
public DateTime DateCreated { get; set; }
```

Controller -

```
public ActionResult Create(int id)
{
      // Attempt to get new customer object
      GetPaymentResponse paymentResponse = _BillingService.GetPayment(id);

     // Check whether response was successful
     if (paymentResponse.State == BaseResponseState.Valid)
     {              
          paymentResponse.Payment.Type.AvailableOptions = paymentResponse.Payment.Type.AvailableOptions.Where(x => x.Value != "BalancingTransaction").ToList();
          ViewData.Model = paymentResponse.Payment;
          return View();
     }           
}
```

I need to pass some additional value to my view via datatype from the model.

E.g. `[DataType("Date"), Format("dd/mm/yy"), StartDate("12-02-2012")]`

Could you please let me know how can I grab these additional value from the template? (I am new to ASP.Net MVC and I am using MVC 3)

Thanks

Comment: please post the controller action and the model.

Comment: I have edited the my answer and added additional information.

Comment: Please post the view that you want to add StartDate to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you specify extra information using attributes, the information must be constant for all the instances of the class in which you define the member. I.e. the `StartDate` will be the same for all instances of your model, becasue the start date specified in the attribute must be a constant.

If that serves your purpoes, you can use a [custom metadata provider](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/showarticle.aspx?ID=715) to get specific [metadata in your model](http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-2-modelmetadata.html) from your custom attributes.

If you need to pass different data fro each case, you have to use any of the overloads of `EditorFor` which allows to pass extra view data. Then you can read that extra information from the `ViewData` in your template.

Be warned that there are some caveats in the metadata providers and custom template implementations, and registration. Take into account if your type can be made nullable, like `DateTime?`

Answer (score 1):

If you use the Model Binding it should take the value properly I believe.

In your view, set the model on the first line, line this:

```
@model MyViewModel
```

and then in your controller, instead of passing the `Model` through the `ViewData`, do something like this:

```
var model = new MyViewModel();
// do stuff with your model here

return View(model);
```

Comment: Do you mean I can access the additional value in [DataType("Date"), Format("dd/mm/yy"), StartDate("12-02-2012")] from my view directly?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that `StartDate` is a property of `Payment`

```
<div class="control-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.StartDate, new { @class = "control-label" })
        <div class="controls" id="date-container">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.StartDate, new { @class="input-append date"})
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.StartDate, null, new { @class = "help-inline" })
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: StartDate is not a property of Payment. It is property of the bootstrap-datepicker. I need to pass this value from Model to my View template. So I don't have to edit my view each time I need to change the start date of the date-picker on my other views

Comment: You mean you want your date picker to always display a set date until the user selects a value, and that set date is a constant?

Comment: Then use a ViewModel, which has StartDate as a property.  You can use a tool like AutoMapper to map your payment entity to the PaymentViewModel and the view model can have a property for StartDate.

Comment: Yes, set date is one of the thing. I also need to add date-picker's date range (startdate & enddate) too.